# This program is taking way too long to run

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code is taking a really long time to run.

It is meant to find the most common word in a text file.

It is in Python 3.5.1.

The Code:

```
cTR = []
cTRC = []


file = open("fileToCompress3.txt","r")
analysis = file.read().split(' ')
file.close()


##### Most Common Word #####
print(1)

for i in range(len(analysis)):

    if analysis[i] not in cTR:
        cTR.extend([analysis[i]])
        cTRC.extend([1])

    elif analysis[i] in cTR:

        for j in range(len(cTR)):

            if cTR[j] == analysis[i]:

                use = j
                break

        cTRC[use] = cTRC[use] + 1
```

Thank You and I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, that’s a really inefficient way to do that – ϴ(n²) time. Python has [a built-in counter type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) that does ϴ(n) comparisons:

```
from collections import Counter

with open("fileToCompress3.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    words = f.read().split()

word_counts = Counter(words)

print(word_counts.most_common(1))
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer, but how can you separate the word from the count as right now it prints like     >>> [('the', 46), ('of', 33), ('\\', 33), ('and', 31), ('to', 25)]

Comment: You can use `zip()` to split them: `cTR, cTRC = zip(*word_counts.most_common())`

Comment: @TheEngineer: What do you want the result to look like? They’re tuples, so the single most common word would be `word_counts.most_common(1)[0][0]`.

Comment: Counter performs n log n comparisons. Look ar the source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/__init__.py

Comment: @enedil: Which part of the source?

Comment: I apologise, if all most common elements are taken, `sorted` is used and that's n log n. If, however `most_common(n)` is used, it's only one time `log len(words))`